# I am working on product listing filters, but not getting logic for one condition, suggest me changes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**I am working on product listing filters, but not getting logic for one condition, suggest me changes**.

My Code Snippet (Some part of my functionality):

```
....
....
if((is_array($origin) && count($origin)>0)||(!is_array($origin) && $origin!=""))
{

    $origin = implode("','",$origin);

    $this->db->select('product_attributes_id');
    $this->db->where('title','Origin');
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    $this->db->where('is_active','Active');
    $result = $this->db->get('tbl_product_attributes');

    if($result->num_rows())
         $paFinRes = $result->result_array();
    else
         $paFinRes = array();

    $paId = $paFinRes[0]['product_attributes_id'];

    $filterQry .= " AND p.`product_id` IN (SELECT `product_id` FROM tbl_product_attributes_price WHERE `product_attributes_id`='".$paId."' AND `product_dimension` IN ('".$origin."'))";
}
....
....
```

this condition is working fine with all other filter parameters..

**Working good for database origin column with following values**

India

Africa

Australia

=======================================================

**Not working good for database origin column with following values**

India

Africa,Russia

Australia,Brazil

========================================================

Please suggest me changes in above if-condition multiple origins (with comma).

Answer (score 0):

Try a foreach loop, that way you won't have to index your row_arrays with integers. From what I understand, something like this can work:

```
$first_query = $this->db->select('product_attributes_id')
                        ->where('title','Origin')
                        ->where('status',1)
                        ->where('is_active','Active')
                        ->get('tbl_product_attributes')
                        ->result_array();

$second_query = $this->db->select('product_attributes_id')
                         ->where('title','Origin')
                         ->where('status',1)
                         ->where('is_active','Active')
                         ->get('tbl_product_attributes')
                         ->num_rows();

if($second_query > 0) {

    foreach($first_query as $row) {
      //Other code
    }
}
else {

   foreach($first_query as $row) {

      $paId = $paFinRes['product_attributes_id'];

      $filterQry .= " AND p.`product_id` IN (SELECT `product_id` FROM tbl_product_attributes_price WHERE `product_attributes_id`='".$paId."' AND `product_dimension` IN ('".$origin."'))";
      $this->db->query($filterQry);
   }
}
```

Not sure that would actually solve your problem, but I see that you don't directly define the query results but instead do it in statements. The values could be mixed up somehow so I changed that to the above.